# Jquery find class child of unkown parent

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have somewhere in the dom one or more classes with the name "summary".
I want to find the closest .summary relative to the element that is calling it.

I managed a solution, but care to see if anyone can further optimize it.

```
   findSummary() {
                let $count = 0;
                let $variations_form;
                let $obj = $('.the_trigger').parent(); // The first parent
                while ($count < 1) {
                    if ($obj.parent().find(".summary").length > 0) {
                        $count++;
                        $variations_form = $obj.parent().find(".summary");
                    } else {
                        $obj = $obj.parent(); //Look inside the next parent, ex: $obj.parent().parent() ... keep adding .parent() until it finds. 
                    }
                }

                return $variations_form;
            }
```

Hope to get feedback.

cheers,
David

Comment: I guess you need to use jquery's `.closest()` function which works like this: `$( "li.item-a" )
  .closest( "ul" )` also see: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

use this:   `$obj.closest('.summary')` 
see the documentation, it takes the closest one: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Hi,

That won't work since it only goes up, i need it to go up and scan the new elements that may show up.
Imagine sevevral bootstrap cols-sm-6 put inside of others cols...

Hope i explained.

Comment: Explain to me in a step-by-step way

Comment: Sure, does this help? on click BTN fires findSummary(),  https://pasteboard.co/I9cxQE8.jpg great pic :) note: there may be more .summary elements on page but only one on the closest parent that has it.